# Use of different priors for groups of idepedent variables in a Bayesian Probit regression model (rstanarm)

Tags: r, logistic-regression, bayesian, rstan, rstanarm

I am using the Bayesian logistic regression (probit) from the rstanarm package to train a model on default events. As inputs the model accepts some financial ratios and some qualitative data. Is there a way where I can actually regularise the coefficients, for the qualitative data only, to be always positive?

For example, when I use a single prior for everything I get these results (I calibrate the model using MCMC, with `set.seed(12345)`):

```
prior <- rstanarm::normal(location = 0, scale = NULL, autoscale = TRUE)

model.formula <-
  formula(paste0('default_events ~ fin_ratio_1 + ',
                 'fin_ratio_2 + fin_ratio_3 +',
                 'fin_ratio_4 + fin_ratio_5 +',
                 'fin_ratio_6 + fin_ratio_7 +',
                 'fin_ratio_8 + Qual_1 + Qual_2 +',
                 'Qual_3 + Qual_4'))

bayesian.model <- rstanarm::stan_glm(model.formula,
                                     family = binomial(link = "probit"),
                                     data = as.data.frame(ds), prior = prior,
                                     prior_intercept = NULL,
                                     init_r = .1, iter=600, warmup=200)
```

The coefficients are the following:

```
summary(bayesian.model)

Estimates:
               mean    sd      2.5%    25%     50%     75%     97.5%
(Intercept)    -2.0     0.4    -2.7    -2.3    -2.0    -1.7    -1.3
fin_ratio_1    -0.7     0.1    -0.9    -0.8    -0.7    -0.6    -0.4
fin_ratio_2    -0.3     0.1    -0.5    -0.4    -0.3    -0.2    -0.1
fin_ratio_3     0.4     0.1     0.2     0.4     0.4     0.5     0.6
fin_ratio_4     0.3     0.1     0.1     0.2     0.3     0.3     0.4
fin_ratio_5     0.2     0.1     0.1     0.2     0.2     0.3     0.4
fin_ratio_6    -0.2     0.1    -0.4    -0.2    -0.2    -0.1     0.0
fin_ratio_7    -0.3     0.1    -0.5    -0.3    -0.3    -0.2    -0.1
fin_ratio_8    -0.2     0.1    -0.5    -0.3    -0.2    -0.1     0.0
Qual_1         -0.2     0.1    -0.3    -0.2    -0.2    -0.1    -0.1
Qual_2          0.0     0.1    -0.1    -0.1     0.0     0.0     0.1
Qual_3          0.2     0.0     0.1     0.1     0.2     0.2     0.3
Qual_4          0.0     0.2    -0.3    -0.1     0.0     0.1     0.3
```

The question is, can I use two different distributions? Like for `fin_ratio_x` variables to use normal and for `Qual_x` variables to use exponential or dirichlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither using different prior families nor inequality restrictions on coefficients are possible with the models supplied by the **rstanarm** package. Either or both is fairly easy to do with the **brms** package or by writing your own Stan program.